# Using font awesome icon by its unicode in edge label in cytoscape is not working

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm trying to use font awesome icon in edge label in `cytoscape.js`
I've referred to the [related issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1322#issuecomment-205871956) and followed it but I was not lucky.

Here's some part of my code:

```js
{
   selector: 'edge',
   style: {
     width: 1.5,
     'curve-style': 'bezier',
     label: '\uf0b0',
     'font-family': 'Font Awesome 5 Free',
     'font-size': 13,
     'font-weight': 900,
   }
},
```

It keeps showing me a small box instead of the icon like below:
[image]

- My project is based on Angular 8
- I've installed the font-awesome dependency through `npm`
- I've added related info into the `angular.json`

What am I missing?

Trying code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-agbuip

Edit: I've linked a simple demonstration

Comment: The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ajhnmcrb/) provided in the [related issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1322#issuecomment-205871956) works fine, so why not take the code from there and see if the issue persists?

Comment: @StephanT. I've already referred that issue and the example but it doesn't work :/

Comment: We can't help with so few lines of code, maybe add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephanT. Here is a simple example of this issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-agbuip. You can see the blank square instead of the desired icon

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue.

Seemingly cytoscape.js is not compatible with font awesome 5 (or vice versa ;-)). Using font awesome 4.7 (https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/) works for now. 
(Remember to use 'font-family': 'FontAwesome' when switching back to font awesome 4).